# how to update array of objects documents, in mongodb directly without findoneandupdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have array of objects,

```
let arr = [
  {
    key:"123",
    data:"dfghj"
  },
  {
    key:"1234",
    data:"dfgfdfej"
  },
  {
    key:"12",
    data:"drrfghj"
  }
]
```

so I want to update each object in db if its present then update that object and if not present in db create that, use mongodb mongoose on node js use updatemany and upsert

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please try to do something... This is not a free coding service!  Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try using bulk write.